# Unexplainable Segfault (double free) in templated Subscriber (polling)

Tags: ros, c++, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey ROS-Community,

I have a very weird error in the attached templated subscriber class, that happens very(!) seldom but is quite frustrating.

Class:

```
/*
 * GenericSubscriber.hpp
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 29, 2012
 *      Author: mriedel
 */

#ifndef GENERICSUBSCRIBER_HPP_
#define GENERICSUBSCRIBER_HPP_

#include <telekyb_defines/telekyb_defines.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>

#include <ros/node_handle.h>

namespace TELEKYB_NAMESPACE
{

template <class T_>
class GenericSubscriber {
protected:
    T_ lastMsg;
    boost::mutex lastMsgLock;

    // Subscriber
    ros::Subscriber sub;

    void msgCallback(boost::shared_ptr<T_ const> msg) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock(lastMsgLock);
        lastMsg = *msg; // copy
    }

public:
    GenericSubscriber(ros::NodeHandle handle, const std::string& topicName, int queue_size) {
        sub = handle.subscribe(topicName, queue_size, &GenericSubscriber<T_>::msgCallback, this);
    }

    virtual ~GenericSubscriber() {};

    T_ getLastMsg() const {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock(lastMsgLock);
        return lastMsg; // implicit copy. Maybe we can do this more efficient?
    }
};

}

#endif /* GENERICSUBSCRIBER_HPP_ */
```

This class enables me to receive generic messages and save the last message in a variable and collect the message with getLastMsg() when needed. Very simple.

Of course it's not the most efficient way to do this (copying the message twice), but it's working for our application. However, every once in a while (seldom) my program crashes when calling getLastMsg() (double free). I don't see where the problem could be located (if in my code or the C++ copy constructor of ROS msgs). Any tips and comments are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48076/unexplainable-segfault-(double-free)-in-templated-subscriber-(polling)/) by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2012-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe a multi-threading problem because your lock does nothing. It should be

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(lastMsgLock);
```

You need to bind it to a variable, otherwise a temporary object is generated that immediately goes out of scope.

Also, why aren't you just storing the shared pointer instead of copying the complete message? It is guaranteed that it will never change. I would also let the getLastMsg method return a const reference, not a copy of the message. The updated class would look like this:

```
template <class T_>
class GenericSubscriber {
protected:
    boost::shared_ptr<const T_> lastMsg;
    boost::mutex lastMsgLock;

    // Subscriber
    ros::Subscriber sub;

    void msgCallback(boost::shared_ptr<T_ const> msg) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(lastMsgLock);
        lastMsg = msg;
    }

public:
    GenericSubscriber(ros::NodeHandle handle, const std::string& topicName, int queue_size) {
        sub = handle.subscribe(topicName, queue_size, &GenericSubscriber<T_>::msgCallback, this);
    }

    virtual ~GenericSubscriber() {};

    const T_ &getLastMsg() const {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(lastMsgLock);
        return *lastMsg;
    }
};
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on 2012-11-12**:
Oh man, I'm so stupid. I actually use a lot of scoped_locks. No idea how I could forget it here and not even see it. Thanks a million.

**Comment by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on 2012-11-12**:
Also thanks for the other suggestions. I'll implement this right now.

**Comment by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on 2012-11-12**:
One more question. Could the const T_& not go out of scope (e.g. a new message overwrite the shared_pointer and it frees the space) while an external thread is trying to access it? Thanks.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-12**:
Right. I missed that. Then you better either return a shared pointer or make a shallow copy of the object.